# Modify Task Scheduler with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, task-scheduler

How does one go about modifying task scheduler via powershell?

Comment: Suffice it to say this is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options. If you are on Vista or higher, then the [Powershell Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) has cmdlets in it for interacting with the Scheduler API.

If you are on an older OS, you would need to use the COM interface:

`$sched = New-Object -COMObject Schedule.Service`